# Media test failure: incorrect BIOS settings, faulty hard drive or weak CMOS battery?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, laptop, bios

I have an Windows 7 [Acer Aspire 4750G](http://www.villman.com/Product-Detail/Aspire_4750G-2312G50Mn) laptop and I am using it almost everyday. Then last night, I am using it as usual, then suddenly all programs stop responding, only the mouse cursor is moving. Then after sometime, it turned off. I opened it then I noticed that the splash screen "Acer" shows up longer than before, then this message appear:

> Copyright (C) 2000-2010 Broadcom Corporation
>
> Copyright (C) 1997-2000 Intel Corporation
>
> All rights reserved.
>
> PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable.
>
> PXE-M0F: Exiting Broadcom PXE ROM

Then a second message appears:

> Operating system not found

I checked the BIOS. The hard drive model and serial number is missing. I also saw **HDD 0:** in the boot order second to the CD Drive. I suspect that cable of the hard drive is faulty. After sometime, I was able to boot the OS two times last night and able to backup some files. But later on, same problems occur: *programs not responding, powers down, same error messages.*

Do I have the right speculations? Any help what to do?

Comment: The message you see is from PXE, a network boot thingy. In most setups, it is placed last in boot sequence, so this message means (1) other boot options failed and (2) ethernet cable is not plugged in. So, it looks more like a problem with HDD. I'd try to put it out and connect to other machine to check if it's alive. Please, note that there's usually no cable for HDD in laptops.

Comment: @at8eqeq3 I completely agree, until that last part. Maybe the OP's specific model doesn't have a HDD ribbon cable but ".. no cable for Laptop HDD's" is an over generalization. I've seen plenty that do. Regardless, I'm absolutely confident that the issue is with your HDD. It's gone bad, it's dying and probably dead. It's not the cable, if it were you would either be able to boot or you wouldn't. The fact that you were "able to boot the OS"  several times afterwards is further indication/symptoms of a failing drive.

Comment: at8eqeq3 and @BiTinerary, this is also my first assumption, a bad HDD. I concluded later to a faulty cable/connection because I was able to boot the OS twice last night. I didn't realize that is a symptom of a failing drive. Any recommendations on what to do and not to do at least to recover the data?

Comment: Spent about an hour putting this together for you (as well as others, I've been meaning to put something together for awhile) so hopefully it is helpful. https://gist.github.com/BiTinerary/d3f75f50a3517dae5fd5